# TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined
```

I know that the for loop executes when the `responseDocument` is still `undefined`. How can I solve this problem?

```js
export default class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      newsFeed: {
        number: null,
        date: null,
        news: null,
      },
    };
  }

  fetchRssFeed() {

    const proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
    const funkyGamesRssFeed = 'https://funkygames.de/rss.xml';
    const request = new Request(proxyUrl + funkyGamesRssFeed);

    return fetch(request).then((results) => {
      results
        .text()
        .then((str) => {
          let responseDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'application/xml');
          const newsItems = responseDocument.getElementsByTagName('item');

          let newsFeed = {
            number: newsItems.length,
            date: new Date(),
            news: [],
          };

          for (let i = 1; i < newsItems.length; i++) {

            let article = new Article();
            article.title = responseDocument.getElementsByTagName('title')[i].textContent;
            
            newsFeed.news.push(article);
          }

        }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
    });

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchRssFeed().catch(e => console.log(e.message));
  }
```

Comment: Why using textContent when you can render it using `render()` method?

Comment: I fetch data from an RSS-Feed. With ". textContent" I got access to the content of the "title"-tag from the RSS-Feed. Why would I use it in `render()`?

Comment: Oh my bad, I thought you set the text content manually instead of using `render()`

Comment: I knew you probably have done it before, but try tracing back to the culprit and logging out all the parts that are associated to `textContent`

Comment: Yes, I did this. When I place `console.log(responseDocument.getElementsByTagName('title')[i].textContent)` in the for-loop I get the title as desired. The error comes only when I assign it to `article.title`.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me when I do this:

```
for (let i = 1; i < newsItems.length; i++) {

        let article = new Article(
          responseDocument.getElementsByTagName('title')[i].textContent,
         );

        newsFeed.news.push(article);
      }
```